# How to deal with Scaled transform in ProjectLocation?

Tags: revit-api

Recently I've stumbled upon a weird Revit 2021 project where `ProjectLocation` contains a scaled transform (got this out through [Revit Lookup plugin](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup)). Revit's own "Report Shared Coordinates" tool on this project shows apparently incorrect values (I suppose they should be multiplied by factor of 1000 - the same as in ProjectLocation's transform).
`ProjectLocation.GetProjectPosition` method we use in our software to get Shared Coordinates also returns the same incorrect values! This leads to an overall messy positioning of all models within the project, as project base points and internal origins are different for all models.
Is it even normal that `ProjectLocation` has scaled transform? If yes, how should model's Shared Coordinates be correctly read via API in this case?

Comment: Where did this model come from? How was it created? Did you create it yourself? In any case, I [asked](https://autodesk.slack.com/archives/C0SR6NAP8/p1692684806002659) the development team for advice for you.

Comment: They suggest: 1000 is an odd number to have returned, as it’s a factor to convert from `MM` to `M`. Check the project units to see if units are consistent.

Comment: Customer says all models are native Revit 2021 models. Project units for both Distance and Length are mm.